# If $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\left[\left(x^5+7x^4+2\right)^c-x\right]$ is a finite, Then limit is

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For a certain value of $'c',\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\left[\left(x^5+7x^4+2\right)^c-x\right]$ is a finite and non-zero,

Then value of limit is

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ Let $\displaystyle x=\frac{1}{y}\;,$ Then $\displaystyle \lim_{y\rightarrow 0}\left[\left(\frac{2y^5+7y+1}{y^5}\right)^c-\frac{1}{y}\right]=\lim_{y\rightarrow 0}\frac{y\cdot \left(2y^5+7y+1\right)^c-y^{5c}}{y^{5c}\cdot y}$

Now how can I solve after that,Help me, Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\bigl((x^5+7x^4+2)^c-x\bigr)$$
is finite, then
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{(x^5+7x^4+2)^c-x}{x}=0$$
and therefore
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{(x^5+7x^4+2)^c}{x}=1\ .$$
Hence
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^5+7x^4+2}{x^{1/c}}=1\ .$$
Now if $\frac1c>5$ then the limit is zero; if $\frac1c<5$ then the limit is infinite; so we must have $c=\frac15$.

To evaluate the limit, write $u=(x^5+7x^4+2)^{1/5}$.  Then we have
$$7x^4+2=u^5-x^5=(u-x)(u^4+u^3x+u^2x^2+ux^3+x^4)$$
and so
$$u-x=\frac{7x^4+2}{u^4+u^3x+u^2x^2+ux^3+x^4}\ .\tag{$*$}$$
Now all the terms in the denominator are much the same as $x\to\infty$: I'll do one and leave you to think about the rest.  We have
$$u^3x=x^4\Bigl(1+\frac7x+\frac{2}{x^5}\Bigr)^{3/5}\ ,$$
and the term in brackets tends to $1$ as $x\to\infty$.  So we can cancel $x^4$ from top and bottom of $(*)$ to get
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}(u-x)=\frac75\ .$$

Answer (score 3):

$\begin{array}\\
(x^5+7x^4+2)^c
&=(x^5(1+7/x+2/x^5))^c\\
&=x^{5c}(1+7/x+2/x^5)^c\\
&\approx x^{5c}(1+c(7/x+2/x^5) + O(1/x^2))\\
&= x^{5c}(1+7c/x + O(1/x^2))\\
&= x^{5c}+7cx^{5c-1} + O(x^{5c-2})\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore
$(x^5+7x^4+2)^c-x
=x^{5c}+7cx^{5c-1} + O(x^{5c-2})-x
$

For this to be finite
for large $x$,
the $x^{5c}$ and $x$ terms
must cancel,
so $5c=1$
or $c=\frac15$.

The remaining term is
$7cx^{5c-1}
=\frac75
$
since
$5c-1
= 0
$.